# Collaborative planning of Facebook posts

Tags: collaboration, scheduling

I'm looking for a free web application where multiple user can collaboratively schedule posts for a Facebook page.

What I'd like is using something similar to google sheets for collaboratively schedule the posts using a format similar to the one of the CSV used by Postcron for bulk upload ([see the video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=53bpbshDpXo)).

Unfortunately, in Postcron one have to upload the CSV from time to time, instead of providing just a link to the google sheet and keep updating just that.

Basically the workflow should be:

- multiple users should add, edit, remove posts easily (we will e.g. create drafts and expand them later)
- when the date and time scheduled for each post is reached, it should be automatically published to Facebook

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Ops. I flagged my question for migration to softwarerecs. I apologise.